# Javascript accordion not working on a particular page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a website which have a separate file for the FAQ, which I import above the footer on all pages. The faq is displayed using accordion tabs with the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var expanded = false;
    var collapsed = true;
    $(".expanderHead").click(function () {
        if (expanded == true) {
            expanded = false;
            collapsed = true;
        } else {
            expanded = true;
            collapsed = false;
        }

        var divid = $(this).attr('tabdata');
        if (expanded == true) {
           // $(this).find('.expanderSign').html("-");
            $("#"+divid).slideToggle();
        }

        $(this).find('.expanderSign').toggleClass("open");
        $(this).find('.expanderSign').toggleClass("closetab");

        if (collapsed == true) {
          //  $(this).find('.expanderSign').html("+");
            $("#"+divid).slideToggle();
        }
    });
});
```

It works fine on all pages, but on a page that is using an other script for the cart, the first 2 tabs in the accordion are not working:

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the other scripts of your page have some errors. Sometimes when a javascript has an error it just stops the others methods